# Getting unknown property: yii\db\ActiveQuery::reg_no

Tags: yii2

I need help on this, I have a model

```
/**
 * This is the model class for table "student_attachment_details".
 *
 * @property integer $createdBy
 * @property string $reg_no
 * @property string $county_attached
 * @property string $closest_town
 * @property string $company_attached
 * @property integer $company_phone_number
 * @property string $is_assessed
 * @property string $location_description
 * @property integer $department_id
 * @property string $allocated_staff_id
 */

 class StudentAttachmentDetails extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
 {
```

But when i try to query the model like this

```
$student_details = StudentAttachmentDetails::find()
                                ->where(['allocated_staff_id'=>'no'])
                                ->limit(1);
```

And then try to get a value with this

```
 $reg_no = $student_details->reg_no;
```

I get this error

```
Getting unknown property: yii\db\ActiveQuery::reg_no
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And how looks your table in DB?

Comment: Please Try `$reg_no = $student_details['reg_no'];`
Or 
I think you have to check model file,below code  is there?
 `public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'student_attachment_details';
    }`

Comment: correct syntax is `$student_details = StudentAttachmentDetails::find()
                                ->where(['allocated_staff_id'=>'no'])
                                ->limit(1)->one();` for get one row and for get all row `$student_details = StudentAttachmentDetails::find()
                                ->where(['allocated_staff_id'=>'no'])
                                ->limit(1)->all();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method `ActiveRecord::find()` returns an `ActiveQuery`; to access the actual model (in your case of class `StudentAttachmentDetails`) you need to call a method to execute the `ActiveQuery`.

something like

```
$student_details = StudentAttachmentDetails::find()
                            ->where(['allocated_staff_id'=>'no'])
                            ->limit(1)->one();
```

will give you the record you are looking for. The docs for `ActiveRecord::find()` can be found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#find()-detail) and `ActiveQuery::one()` [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequeryinterface.html#one()-detail).